# Nodejs Identify output of asyntasks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request, synchronous

I am new to nodejs, I am making multiple get requests with request nodejs api,
with this, I am unable to figure out output of a particular request. How to identify the response of each request individually ? I am using for loop to send multiple requests. If i use recursion, it becomes again synchronous, i just have to separate request with response that too asynchronous. Is it possible ?

In the below code variable 'i' is replace by last iteration .

```
var list = [ 'http://swoogle.umbc.edu/SimService/GetSimilarity?operation=api&phrase1=%20Mobiles%20with%20best&phrase2=Mobiles%20with%20best',
      'http://swoogle.umbc.edu/SimService/GetSimilarity?operation=api&phrase1=%2520Mobiles%2520with%2520best&phrase2=what%20is%20a%20processor']

function ss(list){
    for(var i in list) {
        request(list[i], function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log( i + " " +body);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async) to perform async requests.
Spefically, you can use `async.each` or `async.eachSeries`.

The difference between the 2 of them is that `each` will run all the requests in parallel, just as the `for` loop does, but will retain context, as opposed to `eachSeries` which will run the requests one at a time(second iteration will begin only when you called the callback function of the first). Also - there are other options for more specific use cases(like `eachLimit` for instance).

example code using `each`:

```
var list = [ 'http://swoogle.umbc.edu/SimService/GetSimilarity?operation=api&phrase1=%20Mobiles%20with%20best&phrase2=Mobiles%20with%20best',
      'http://swoogle.umbc.edu/SimService/GetSimilarity?operation=api&phrase1=%2520Mobiles%2520with%2520best&phrase2=what%20is%20a%20processor']

function ss(list){
    async.each(list, function(listItem, next) {
        request(listItem, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log( listItem + " " +body);
            }

            next();
            return;
        })
    },
    //finally mehtod
    function(err) {
        console.log('all iterations completed.')
    })
}
```

Comment: Its works like synchronous, taking time for all responses. can we identify response for specific request in asynchronous way like @Gilad  Bison code?

Comment: As I described above - you can use each instead of eachSeries. I edited the answer